# Select columns from big file, using rows from another file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

I want to select the columns from a big file ,based on the rows from another file.
This problem has been answered here but both the solutions does not work.

https://www.biostars.org/p/166527/

DATA.TXT

```
head0 head1 head2 head3 head4  
1 25 1364 22 13  
2 10 215 1 22
```

LIST.TXT

```
head0  
head4
```

Desired output:

```
head0 head4  
1 13  
2 22
```

The first command of the second solution works.

```
cat file1.txt | cut -f$(grep -wFf file2.txt TMP | cut -f1 | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g') > OUTPUT cut: option requires an argument -- f
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Ron

Comment: You may receive some downvotes for using a URL instead of putting your code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on my Mac.

1. you need to ensure that your files are tab-separated, and have no leading or trailing whitespace.
2. that sed command can be replaced by `paste -sd,`
3. leaving:

   ```
   cut -f"$(grep -wFf LIST.TXT TMP | cut -f1 | paste -sd,)" DATA.TXT
   ```

But, use the awk solution, it's much tidier and doesn't use a tmp file, and is much more forgiving about whitespace:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR == FNR {header[$1] = 1; next}
    FNR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in header) column[i] = 1}
    {for (i in column) printf "%s" OFS, $i; print ""}
' headers file
```

---

After a bit of play, the pipeline that works (whiteout needing a tmp file) is

```
cut -f"$(head -1 DATA.TXT | tr '\t' '\n' | nl | grep -Fwf LIST.TXT | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd,)" DATA.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the columns output in the order defined by list.txt:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    name2out[$1] = ++numOutFlds
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        outFldNr = name2out[$inFldNr]
        out2in[outFldNr] = inFldNr
    }
}
{
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr < numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk list.txt data.txt
head0 head4
1 13
2 22
```